# Which SKPhysicsBody is most efficient for static scene elements?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I've got a side-scroller platform type of game, so there are many static scenery obstacles that the player can collide with.  Which `SKPhysicsBody` type is more efficient:  `-bodyWithRectangleOfSize` or `-bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect`?

Comment: edge based bodies are always more efficient for static collision shapes

Comment: Actually, I just found this in the SpriteKit docs:  "An edge-based body is more expensive to compute than a volume-based body. This is because the bodies it interacts with can potentially be on either side of an open edge or on the inside or outside of a closed shape. "

Comment: Using `-bodyWithRectangleOfSize` with `physicsBody.dynamic = NO` will result in similar behaviour as `-bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect`. Since volume based body is more efficient, you can use this approach.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely what I do already.